Cannot generate OpenAPI specs using smallrye openapi dependency plugin and jaxrs interface
I'm developing a microservices composed of different maven modules.
The rest-api submodule is the one I'm using to define the REST API interfaces.
An interface is defined as such:
    @Path("/identity")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public interface IIdentityResource {

    /**
     * Request a Time Based One Time Password (TOTP) for user's email verification.
     *
     * @param email The user's email
     *              The email must be valid and not already verified
     *              The email must be associated to a user
     * @return      The generated TOTP
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/account/verification/send-totp")
    @APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "204",
            description = "Account successfully verified"
        ),
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "400",
            description = "Bad Request - Invalid account verification data",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponseDTO.class))
        ),
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "401",
            description = "Not Authorized - Invalid or expired credentials",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponseDTO.class))
        ),
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "403",
            description = "Forbidden - Access to resource is forbidden",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponseDTO.class))
        ),
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "404",
            description = "Not Found - Account or verification data not found",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponseDTO.class))
        ),
        @APIResponse(
            responseCode = "500",
            description = "Internal Server Error - Unexpected error",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponseDTO.class))
        )
    })
    void requestVerificationTOTP(@Valid AccountVerificationOTPRequest accountVerificationOTPRequest);

    /**
     * Verify the user's email with the given TOTP.
     *
     * @param email The user's email
     *              The email must be valid and not already verified
     *              The email must be associated to a user
     * @param totp  The TOTP
     * @return      The generated TOTP
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/account/verification/verify")
    void verifyAccountTOTP(@Valid AccountVerificationRequest accountVerificationRequest) throws BadRequestException, NotFoundException, ForbiddenException, NotAuthorizedException, InternalServerErrorException ;

    /**
     * Request a Time Based One Time Password (TOTP) for user's password reset.
     *
     * @param email The user's email
     *              The email must be valid and not already verified
     *              The email must be associated to a user
     * @return      The generated TOTP
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/account/password-reset/send-totp")
    void requestResetTOTP(@Valid PasswordResetOTPRequest passwordResetOTPRequest);

    /**
     * Reset the user's password with the given TOTP.
     *
     * @param email The user's email
     *              The email must be valid and not already verified
     *              The email must be associated to a user
     * @param totp  The TOTP
     * @return      The generated TOTP
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/account/password-reset/update-password")
    void resetPasswordTOTP(@Valid PasswordResetRequest passwordResetRequest) throws BadRequestException, NotFoundException, ForbiddenException, NotAuthorizedException, InternalServerErrorException ;

}

And my pom.xml file:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-composer</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </parent>
    
        <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
                <artifactId>smallrye-open-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>smallrye-open-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
                    <version>3.13.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate-schema</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>target/openapi.yaml</outputFile>                    <!-- or JSON format -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>

When i try to generate the openapi specifications through >mvn clean compile -pl rest-api or just mvn clean compile -pl rest-api smallrye-open-api:generate-schema the definition is empty:
---
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Generated API
  version: "1.0"
paths: {}


